# NSURLConnection returns error but server shows request status 200

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm facing a problem with either NSURLSession or NSURLConnection

I'm trying to make (for example) 200 NSURLRequests. While sending requests, i shut down my phone connection (plane mode or shutdown wifi) and switch it back on and shut it down ...

Sometimes, the NSURLSession response or NSURLConnection response returns me an error (NSData is nil, as the NSURLResponse) but when i check on my server, i see the request with a 200 status. If I use a proxy like Charles, i also see the request.

It seems that when a request is made, if the connection is lost then found again quickly, the request is still done even though an error is returned

How can i be sure that a request was truly not sent to the server because the connection was lost ?

Here's an example of code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var queue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    queue.name = "Queue"
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func sendRequests(sender: UIButton) {
    for(var i = 1; i<=200; i++) {
        let request = Request(page:i)
        queue.addOperation(request)
    }
}

}
```

And my NSOperation doing the synchronous request :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Request: NSOperation {

var page: Int

init(page: Int) {
    self.page = page
}

override func main() {
    autoreleasepool {
        self.send()
    }
}

func send() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost?p=\(page)")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
    request.networkServiceType = NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType.NetworkServiceTypeBackground

    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?
    var data: NSData?

    data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

    if(data == nil) {
        println("\(page) FAILED TO SEND")
    } else {
        println("\(page) SUCCESS")
    }

    if(error != nil) {
        println("\(page) ERROR : \(error?.debugDescription)")
    }

    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        println("STATUS \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
    }
}   
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Seems like if i disable Keepalive on my web server, the problem is solved ... but that's not a good solution for me :(

Comment: Also, the problem only occurs on iOS 8 (i don't have the problem if i build with iOS7 deployment target)